# Opcache preloading and missing App_KernelProdContainer.preload.php

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, preload, opcache

After following the documentation, my new OPCache settings are like this:

```
opcache.preload_user=www-data
opcache.preload=/var/www/vhosts/.../httpdocs/.../var/cache/prod/App_KernelProdContainer.preload.php
opcache.memory_consumption=1024
opcache.interned_strings_buffer=256
opcache.max_accelerated_files=20000
opcache.validate_timestamps=0
```

By default, inside `var/cache/prod` folder there is a file named `srcApp_KernelProdContainer.preload.php`.

After deleting ***/cache*** folder & restarting ***PHP-FPM***, `App_KernelProdContainer.preload.php` is not created.

Should I rename `App_KernelProdContainer.preload.php` to `srcApp_KernelProdContainer.preload.php` or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you shouldn't add this file directly to your PHP settings, since as you discovered it makes the whole thing very brittle. You should also not rename it or anything, since it's generated automatically.

What Symfony  does in latter versions is create a "preload" file.

The Symfony 4 flex recipe includes [this one](https://github.com/symfony/recipes/blob/master/symfony/framework-bundle/4.4/config/preload.php).

```
<?php

if (file_exists(dirname(__DIR__).'/var/cache/prod/srcApp_KernelProdContainer.preload.php')) {
    require dirname(__DIR__).'/var/cache/prod/srcApp_KernelProdContainer.preload.php';
}

if (file_exists(dirname(__DIR__).'/var/cache/prod/App_KernelProdContainer.preload.php')) {
    require dirname(__DIR__).'/var/cache/prod/App_KernelProdContainer.preload.php';
}
```

On Symfony 5.1+ you have something [like this](https://github.com/symfony/recipes/blob/master/symfony/framework-bundle/5.1/config/preload.php).

Notice that what this file requires the preload script conditionally. This way, if it doesn't exist, it won't just kill the PHP interpreter.

If you do not currently have this file; you can create it manually, or just copy it from the recipe.

Add **this** file to your `opcache.preload` settings on `php.ini`, not the generated preloading script directly.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer,  Symfony 4 auto generate **preload** file as you explain.
So, I just removed `opcache.preload=/var/www/vhosts/.../httpdocs/.../var/cache/prod/App_KernelProdContainer.preload.php` because it's auto created inside `var\cache\prod`.
But I didn't understand your last added line:
 _Add this file to your opcache.preload settings on php.ini, not the generated preloading script directly_

Comment: The `opcache.preload` option should point to the `preload.php` file. `opcache.preload="/path/to/preload.php`.